# Guidance in/on research and life

Tags: prepositions, british-english

Should I use "guidance on" or "guidance in" in the following sentence? Google search showed that "on" is more often used.

> Thank you for the guidance not only on research and statistics but on life in general.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> **guidance on**

is much more common and

> **guidance in**

is mostly used in contexts
where 'guidance' was being used as a single word.

[lengusa | guidance on](https://lengusa.com/search/guidance%20on)

[lengusa | guidance in](https://lengusa.com/search/guidance%20in)

You should use 'on' in this sentence as you are meaning 'guidance' in these specific topics.